# Is there support for Google Cloud tools in Jetbrains Rider

Tags: rider, google-cloud-intellij

We are working on an app for deployment to Google Cloud. So, it would be nice if we could integrate the Google Cloud tools with Rider. There is a module to integrate Intellij with the GCP tools but it doesn't work in Rider.

I've been beating at this for two days and have concluded that Rider does NOT support the GCP tools. Am I right, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the team that builds Google Cloud Tools plugin for IntelliJ. You are correct that the plugin does not currently support Rider.

However, we are actively working to expand the plugin to other Jetbrains IDEs. Rider is one of the IDEs we will look at. Unfortunately I don't have a more specific timeline for you.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1896
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1472

Comment: FYI Cloud Tools for IntelliJ is now compatible with Rider.  However only GCS and Cloud Source Repo browsing are currently supported in that IDE.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-google-cloud-tools

Comment: @PatrickFlynn since it supports Rider does that mean c#?

Comment: @mbalsam I'm no longer on the team but there are no C# specific features AFAIK.

Comment: I spoke with the developer of the plugin and he said that he's currently working on .net support.